# Strategy to compute limit of a complex function

Tags: limits, education

Does a "standard" procedure to compute limits of the complex functions exist?
I know that this question is generic. I expect a generic reply.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: l'Hospital's rule... possibly iterated.

Comment: "complex function" is  abit confusing, better use difficult or complicated

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score -1):

When we are dealing with indeterminate form of complicated expression, the standard and more effective method to calculate the limit is of course [**Taylor's series**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) expansion.

In that way we can reduce any term in polynomial form and the limit becomes easy do solve. The difficult is to select the correct (i.e. minimum) order of expansion and to deal with the remainder terms (usually in little-o or big-O notation).

For example by Taylor's series, with some practice, it is easy to see that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \sin^2 \left( \arctan (\log (1+\sin x) \right) -1+\cos(\tan x)} {\arcsin^4(\sin(\log (1-\tan(x^2))))+e^{\sin^2x}-1}=\frac12$$

indeed it correspons to

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ x^2-1+\frac12x^2+o(x^2)} {x^8+1+x^2-1+o(x^2)}=
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \frac12x^2+o(x^2)} {x^2+o(x^2)}=\frac12$$